# Bootstrap colorpicker basic example does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use a color picker plugin for bootstrap : https://farbelous.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/index.html

It uses bootstrap 4 and Jquery

When trying the very basic code example, published by the developer, in my website or in JS Fiddle, the color picker just does not work properly (you should see a clickable square on the left and be able to pick a color with it)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmscz0L7/3/)

What am I doing wrong ? I thought it might be the imports that did not work, so I used CDNs but it does not change anything

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmscz0L7/9/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.3/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Bootstrap Colorpicker Demo</h1>
      <input id="demo" type="text" class="form-control" value="rgb(255, 128, 0)" />
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.3/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      // Basic instantiation:
      $('#demo').colorpicker();

      // Example using an event, to change the color of the .jumbotron background:
      $('#demo').on('colorpickerChange', function(event) {
        $('.jumbotron').css('background-color', event.color.toString());
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is fixed version of your code: [Fixed version.](https://jsfiddle.net/xmscz0L7/8)

There was a problem with loading `jQuery` from CDN.

Chrome returned error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.

So I've re-added CDN and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a slight mistake. Please go to your `jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` - the link is not correct. Replace your`jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` link with the following:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>jQueryUI | Color Picker</title>

    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js">
    </script>
    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>
    <link href=
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Include Pre-compiled files from link or
        download the files in your localhost folder -->
    <script src=
"jquery.colorpicker.js">
    </script>
    <link href=
"jquery.colorpicker.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style>
        
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   
    
    <br/>

    <body>
        Pick a color :
        <input type="text" id="my_color_picker">

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    $("#my_color_picker").colorpicker();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</body>

</html>
```

Note:- Download jquery.colorpicker.js & jquery.colorpicker.css files from https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.